# How to center absolute div (text) above relative div (image) responsively?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center, absolute

I'm building a template with Twitter Bootstrap and trying to get a text centered horizontally and vertically above a image, for example:
[image]

I'm trying with this:

```
<div class="container"> <!--Bootstrap-->
  <div class="row"> <!--Bootstrap-->
    <div class="col-md-4"> <!--Bootstrap-->

        <div class="box">
           <div class="thumb"><img src="..."></div>
           <div class="title">Post title</div>
        </div>

    </div> <!--Bootstrap-->
  </div> <!--Bootstrap-->
</div> <!--Bootstrap-->

.box {height:350px; width:100%; border:4px solid #fff;}
.thumb {position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; overflow: hidden;}
.thumb img{width:100%; height:100%; overflow: hidden;}
.title {position:absolute;}
```

With this, if I use some value to ***top*** to the div ***title*** it appears above the img, but I can't get to center it neither horizontally or vertically.

It doesn't work either with all I searched until now: ***left:50%***, ***left:0*** and ***right:0***; ***margin:auto***, etc...

Also I'm not looking for to use the img as a css background.

How can I get this right?

Comment: can you use `display:table-cell` in this project?

Comment: I tried using `display:table` to the **thumb** div and `display:table-cell` plus `vertical-align:middle` to the **title** div, but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code doesn't work because you are not applying `top:0` and `width:100%` or `left` and `right` values.  You also need to add `position:relative` to `box` so that the absolutely positioned title will place correctly.  My suggestion to center the variably tall title is to use `display:table-cell`.  The only problem with this (other than compatibility) is that it also requires another element added (some wrapping element around the text of `.title`).  You can see this solution demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/dx44c/3/

Compatibility for table-cell: http://caniuse.com/#search=table

required markup:

```
    <div class="box">
        <div class="thumb"><img src="//lorempixel.com/712/342"></div>
        <div class="title"><div>Post title</div></div>
    </div>
```

the CSS needed:

```
.box {position: relative; height:350px; width:100%; border:4px solid #fff;}
.thumb {position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; overflow: hidden;}
.thumb img{width:100%; height:100%; overflow: hidden;}
.title {
    position:absolute;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: white;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}
.title div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0 20%;
}
```

edit: better example added with more text and some padding on the `table-cell`

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But I guess because of the `width:100%` and `height:100%` on `.title` I don't get to use opacity hover effects on the `.thumb img` (therefore, `.thumb img:hover`). Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I would instead use `.box:hover .thumb img`.  It doesn't look like you are needing to support IE 6 so I think we can rule out the problem of it not being an anchor that has the `:hover` rule. :P

edit: here's an example. http://jsfiddle.net/dx44c/4/

Answer (score 0):

to put the title in center horizontally just give the .title text-align: center; make the position relative and give a bottom 60%; like the bellow one:

```
<head>
<style>
.box {position:relative; height:350px; width:100%; border:4px solid #fff;}
.thumb {position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; overflow: hidden;}
.thumb img{width:100%; height:100%; overflow: hidden;}

.title {position:relative; 
font-weight: bold; 
bottom: 60%;
color: white; 
text-align: center;
padding: 0px 10px;
width: 97%;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"> <!--Bootstrap-->
  <div class="row"> <!--Bootstrap-->
    <div class="col-md-4"> <!--Bootstrap-->

        <div class="box">
           <div class="thumb"><img src="http://cache.graphicslib.viator.com/graphicslib/media/a8/sunset-cruise-on-the-sydney-harbour-photo_5361064-fit468x296.jpg"></div>
           <div class="title">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
            </div>
        </div>

    </div> <!--Bootstrap-->
  </div> <!--Bootstrap-->
</div> <!--Bootstrap-->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/flexbox) is another option for vertical centering.

Demo: **http://jsfiddle.net/cQ5GG/** (add additional vendor prefixes if needed)

```
<style>
.thumb {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.caption {
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font: bold 16px/150% Arial,sans-serif;
}
</style>

<div class="thumb" style="background: url(http://css-tricks.com/wp-content/csstricks-uploads/transpBlack50.png), url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/)">
    <div class="caption">
        This is my caption<br>
        Multiple lines<br>
        For example...
    </div>
</div>
```